# Java 8 Optional how to deal with too many orElses

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

Let's take a look at the example without lambdas:

```
Credentials credentials = CredentialService.get(id);
if (credentials != null && credentials.isActive()) {
    User user = UserService.get(credentials.getUserId());
    if (user != null)
        return Status.ok(user);
}
return Status.bad();
```

As you can see, `Status.ok()` will be returned only if user isn't `null`. Otherwise, `Status.bad()` will be returned. Now with lambdas (Service's methods now returns `Optional<T>`):

```
return CredentialService.get(id)
        .filter(Credentials::isActive)
        .map(credentials -> UserService.get(credentials.getUserId())
            .map(Status::ok)
            .orElse(Status.bad())              
        ).orElse(Status.bad());
```

Now I have to return `Status.bad()` two times (in real code, about 4-5). Is it a way to return `Status.bad()` once?

Comment: I don't have any more information about the details of these lines of code. But maybe it is only necessary to return the last `.orElse(Status.bad())` Maybe you can think about it.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, `Optional<Credentials>`, so `filter` exists.
@smsnheck, You're right, it only depends `Optional` in the remaining `orElse`. It works with `.orElse(Optional.empty()).orElse(null)`. Is it a way to make it not confusing?

Comment: It's also possible that your code will look like crap no matter whether you use optional or not because the design is off. The functional components of Java 8 are just another programming methodology, not magical fairy dust.

Comment: I agree with @Kayaman. I think you should reconsider your design of your classes and services.

Comment: It's just an example to improve the understanding of the issue. Of course, the design is better :)

Comment: @delver That's not always given. I find it very poor programming style to throw lambdas at every problem when a longer lasting and more elegant solution would be something like adding a `getActiveCredentials(id)` (as an example) to the service layer.

Comment: @Kayaman: the problem is not the use of lambda expressions or `Optional`, but the logic that is already contained in the original code. For a possibly long chain of things that might fail, a generic `Status.bad()` is returned, leaving the caller, and in the end the user, without any hint about *why* it has failed. It’s like the infamous `java.io.File.delete()` returning a `boolean`, `false` implying *something* went wrong, guess what. Well, today, there is the new `java.nio.file.Files.delete(Path)` signalling different error conditions via different exception types. Just as food for thoughts…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can guess UserService::get return Optional in this case you better to use flatMap:

```
CredentialService.get(id)
         .filter(Credentials::isActive)
            .flatMap(credentials -> UserService.get(credentials.getUserId())
            .map(Status::ok)
            .orElse(Status.bad())
```